# Same thread keeps getting rescheduled after yielding

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to create a very threaded simple producer consumer toy implementation, but I'm running into a strange issue where the same consumer thread keeps getting rescheduled over and over again even though I am yielding control.

Here is an abridged version of my code. The Main method is simple , I start one producer and two consumer threads. I join to the producer thread and detach the two consumer threads. A getchar at the end of the main method keeps the program from exiting.

```
std::vector<int> UnprocessedValues;
std::vector<int> ProcessedValues;       
std::mutex unprocessed_mutex;

void AddUnprocessedValue()
{  
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; ++i)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(unprocessed_mutex);
            UnprocessedValues.push_back(i);
            std::cout << "Thread id : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " ";
            printf("Unprocessed value added %i \n", UnprocessedValues.back());
        }
    }
}

void ProcessCurrentValue()
{
    while (true)
    {
            unprocessed_mutex.lock();
   
            if (UnprocessedValues.empty())
            {
                std::cout << "Thread id : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " ";
                printf("is waiting for values \n");
                unprocessed_mutex.unlock();
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
            else
            {
                // Process value
                unprocessed_mutex.unlock();
            }
    }
}
```

I expect that when there are no values present for consumers, they will both yield and end up giving the producer a chance to produce more.

In practice I see a single consumer getting stuck on waiting for values. Eventually the program rights itself, but something is obviously wrong.

If I was seeing the two consumers print that they are waiting in alternate, I would think that somehow the producer is getting shafted by the two consumers taking turns, but the actual result is that the same thread keeps getting rescheduled even though it just yielded.

Finally, when I change the if case from

```
if (UnprocessedValues.empty())
{
    std::cout << "Thread id : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " ";
    printf("is waiting for values \n");
    unprocessed_mutex.unlock();
    std::this_thread::yield();
}
```

to

```
if (UnprocessedValues.empty())
{
    unprocessed_mutex.unlock();
    std::this_thread::yield();
    std::cout << "Thread id : " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " ";
    printf("is waiting for values \n");
}
```

I never see a busy wait. I realize that I could use a condition variable to fix this problem and I have already seen that using a small sleep instead of a yield works. I am just trying to understand why the yield would not work.

Comment: One might ask why the lock is outside of the second if condition. It's because the Processing removes the topmost value from the UnprocessedValues vector. If I made the critical section smaller, then its possible to have two threads get into the second block and one of them empties it while the other still expects data to be in there.

Comment: @WhozCraig I agree a condition var would solve the problem , as I mentioned at the end of my original question.
In this specific case, I'm less interested in solving the problem in this case and more interested in where my understanding is failing me :)

Comment: yield is not a guaranteed sleep. At best it is a hint to reschedule this thread behind others of the same priority in the wait queue. Consider, for example, if there *is no wait queue* (consider a multi-core box with literally spare cores available), there is no reason *not* to let the thread immediately continue (but also no guarantee that it will).The behavior is *highly* dependent to the OS and its use of available hardware. If you want predictability, use a condition variable (and even then, make sure to account for spurious events).